# Angular 9 or 10 + Angular Material 10: import could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ivy

I did a new project with Angular 9 and last version of material. When I imported some Material's classes, I had this error:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/label.d.ts:10:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatLabel has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
>
> 10 export declare class MatLabel {
> ~~~~~~~~
> node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/hint.d.ts:20:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatHint has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
>
> 20 export declare class MatHint {
> ~~~~~~~
> src/app/material.module.ts:12:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
>
> 12 export class MaterialModule {}
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/label.d.ts:10:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatLabel has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
>
> 10 export declare class MatLabel {
> ~~~~~~~~
> node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/hint.d.ts:20:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatHint has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
>
> 20 export declare class MatHint {
> ~~~~~~~
> src/app/material.module.ts:12:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
>
> 12 export class MaterialModule {}
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatLabel,
  MatHint,
} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatLabel, MatHint],
  exports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatLabel, MatHint],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CarouselComponent } from './carousel/carousel.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CrudComponent } from './crud/crud.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layout/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PrivHeaderComponent } from './layout/priv-header/priv-header.component';
import { PrivMenuComponent } from './layout/priv-menu/priv-menu.component';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './layout/main-menu/main-menu.component';
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './layout/main-header/main-header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CrudComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PrivHeaderComponent,
    PrivMenuComponent,
    MainMenuComponent,
    MainHeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mini-aplicacion",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

I tried to delete node_modules and install it again. Also, I update Angular version to 10 and Material version, but the problem persisted.

I review other similar issues, but non of the solutions fix my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatLabel and MatHint are include in the MatFormFieldModule, you don't have to import them. Import only MatFormFieldModule as described [in the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api)

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field'; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule],
  exports: [MatFormFieldModule],
})
```